# How to derive inverse square relation in Newton's Law of Gravitation from Kepler's laws?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion, celestial-mechanics

I read Feynman's Lost lecture a while ago. In that spirit, I'm trying to do a more simplified version of coming up with the inverse square relation.

Using Kepler's 2nd,

$ A_1 = \frac{1}{2}r_1^2\theta_1 $

$ A_2 = \frac{1}{2}r_2^2\theta_2 $

$ A_1 = \frac{1}{2}r_1^2\omega_1 t $

$ A_2 = \frac{1}{2}r_2^2\omega_2 t$

$ m\omega_1 A_1 = \frac{1}{2}mr_1^2\omega_1^2 $

$ m\omega_2A_2 = \frac{1}{2}mr_2^2\omega_2^2 $

$ mv_1 A_1 = \frac{1}{2}r_1^2F_1 $

$ mv_2A_2 = \frac{1}{2}r_2^2F_2 $

Dividing one by the other, I get

$\frac{F_1}{F_2} = \frac{v_1}{v_2}\frac{r_2^2}{r_1^2}$

which is almost there, except for the $\frac{v_1}{v_2}$

Any suggestions on how to proceed from here?

Comment: Try the third law which relates period to distance?

Comment: There is a derivation at:  [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kepler's_laws_of_planetary_motion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kepler's_laws_of_planetary_motion).  Look under the subheading "The inverse square law" for the derivation.

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/128245/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 2):

Consider a circular orbit (Kepler's first law tells us this is possible, as circles are particular cases of ellipses). By Kepler's second law, the speed $v$ is constant along the orbit. We can obtain its dependence on $r$ using **Kepler's third law**: $T^2\propto r^3$. The result is $v^2\propto 1/r$.

For the orbit to be circular, the force should satisfy
\begin{equation}
  F(r)=m\frac{v^2}{r}\propto\frac{1}{r^2}.
\end{equation}

---

We can also find the **direction of the force** from Kepler's laws! We work in two dimensions because Kepler's first law tell us that the orbits stay in a plane. The acceleration in radial coordinates is
\begin{equation}
  \vec{a} =
  (\ddot{r}-r\dot{\theta}^2)\hat{r} +
  (r\ddot{\theta}+2\dot{r}\dot{\theta})\hat{\theta}.
\end{equation}
Notice that the $\hat{\theta}$ component of the acceleration is just $\frac{1}{r}\frac{d}{dt}(r^2\dot{\theta})$, and that $r^2\dot{\theta}$ is the areal velocity, which is constant by Kepler's second law. Therefore, the acceleration has the direction of $\hat{r}$, and so does the force. The latter should then be of the form
\begin{equation}
  \vec{F}(\vec{r})=-F(r)\hat{r},
\end{equation}
where the dependence only on $r$ and not $\theta$ is a consequence of the isotropy of space.

Comment: I have gone through this way & the differential equation it leads to in our mechanics course. All I want to ask is that , is there any way to solve it in Cartesian ( x , y ) without polar ?

Comment: That is a great answer. I have always wondered how did Newton come up with his formula. Now, one can see a possible way he may used to get it.